# getting the local time

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

```
int tzO = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now) ? -4 : -5;
```

(It is a single line of code.  Some browsers wrap it to two lines.) Why does this code suck?

Comment: Is there a problem with the code? If not, this question would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Why does it suck? Well, that's quite subjective, but I can tell you a couple of things:

- The `TimeZone` class is deprecated.  Well, it's not been marked obsolete, but all of the guidance, including [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe5cd9e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says to use `TimeZoneInfo` instead.
- You're taking the current time zone, and then using it to determine a offset value manually. One would think you were after the offset of the current timezone - not one of the two you hardcoded.
- When you pass `DateTime.Now`, you're relying on the local time.  That's not horrible, but it is *possible* that you have an ambiguous time reference, due to a daylight savings "fall-back" transition.  It would be better to be explicit and use `UtcNow` instead.
- You are returning an integer whole number of hours.  Many time zones use half-hour offsets, and there are a few rare ones that are 45 minute offset.  You should use a `TimeSpan` for this instead.

So the version of this code that doesn't "suck" would be:

```
TimeSpan offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.UtcNow()` to get the UTC Time.